# How are IP addresses assigned?

Tags: ip, network, ip-address

1) If I buy a new computer, I haven't connected to the internet yet, don't I have ip address?

2) if I get the ip in one county, IANA gives me the ip depends on my location (first numbers), if I change my location and connect again, shall I get another one?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Network Engineering.  We hope you will become a contributing member of this community.

Let me answer the second question first:

> 2) if I get the ip in one count[r]y, IANA gives me the ip depends on my
>   location (first numbers), if I change my location and connect again,
>   shall I get another one?

A few misconceptions here.  While IANA does globally coordinate IP addresses, They are assigned by [Internet registries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) (there are five around the world).  The registries assign addresses although they don't do it for individuals.  Your ISP will assign you an address (from their registry-assigned range) when you connect up to them.  Since that address is associated with that ISP, it's only good while you're connected to their network. If you change locations, your new ISP will assign you a new address.

IP addresses were originally allocated as requested, so there is no location information in the "first numbers" of an IP address.

> 1) If I buy a new computer, I haven't connected to the internet yet,
>   don't I have ip address?

No.  On the global Internet, addresses are given by ISPs (see note).  You can configure an IP address manually on your computer, and if you are connected to your own private network, any addressing scheme will do.  But if you connect to the Internet, you need an address assigned by the registry (usually through your ISP).  Otherwise it would be like assigning yourself your own random phone number.

Note: If you are a large organization, you can ask the registry to assign you a block of addresses for your organization's use.  You will have to justify why you can't use ISP-assigned addresses.  Presently, there are no more IPv4 addresses available to give out.